# IndexPath values are changing while scrolling UITableviewcells?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

While moving from `first view controller` to `second view controller` I'm saving indexpaths in a array and in the return when loading a table in `first view controller`, if the current indexpath is in the saved indexpaths array I have to create a custom accessory button.

But, when scrolling `UITableview` along with the required cell another cell also getting custom button. When I'm printing the `NSindexPaths` while scrolling I'm getting random values instead of normal one's.

For the above I'm using the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // NSLog(@"newdata value is =%d",newData);
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.positionsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playersInPosition"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"playersInPosition"]autorelease];
    }
    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [lblName setText:[inputData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    UILabel *pname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    [pname setText:[appDelegate.playersNFL objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

      for (NSIndexPath *object in appDelegate.indexPathList) {
    if ([object isEqual:indexPath]) {
        NSLog(@"saved index path values are =%@",appDelegate.savedIndexPath);
        UIButton *button = [self ChangeAccessoryButtonStyle:appDelegate.indexPathList[0]];
        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }
    }
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: indetifir your cell with `NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];`

Comment: Where do you save the indexPaths ? Can you explain more what are you trying to achieve ? Also, because of cell reusing, when the `isEqual`'s `if` evaluates to false you should have an else branch with `cell.accessoryView = nil`.

Comment: Hi @Templar I have saved indexPaths in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}       Since, I have accessorydetaildisclosurebutton in first view controller...thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember any part of documentation saying the index-paths are meant to be reused by a table view, it might be a good idea then to compare the objects with a [designed function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> compare:
>
> Indicates the depth-first traversal order of the receiving
>   index path and another index path.
>
> -(NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>
> Parameters
>
> indexPath Index path to compare. This value must not be nil. If the
>   value is nil, the behavior is undefined.
>
> Return Value
>
> The depth-first
>   traversal ordering of the receiving index path and indexPath.
>
> - NSOrderedAscending: The receiving index path comes before indexPath.
> - NSOrderedDescending: The receiving index path comes after indexPath.
> - NSOrderedSame: The receiving index path and indexPath are the same
>     index path.
>
> Availability
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> Declared In
>
> NSIndexPath.h

Comment: Hi @A-Live thanks for reply...all the code is working fine. But, indexpath values for the cells in the uitableview is changing while scrolling.. I just want to know whether I'm doing anything incorrectly while declaring cell contents in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line and create cell each time.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.positionsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playersInPosition"];
```